# Create new PFUser using code without logging in as this new PFUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I am creating a new PFUser to be a "sub user" of the currently logged in user.

For example Master is logged in and decides to create a Junior User.

The Junior user will have a different PFRole to the Master.

I can create a new User via

```
    var newUser = PFUser()
    newUser.email = "someemail@gmail.com"
    newUser.username = "Demo Subuser"
    newUser.password = "12341234"


    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (newUser, error) -> Void in

        println(error)

    }
```

The user is created, but the problem is I am logged out of the master account and logged in as the Junior user.

How can I create a new PFUser without it logging into that account.

Ideally, I want to send an email to the new subuser stating, welcome here is your username and details.

Maybe I should be using CloudCode ?

Thanks

Comment: got it to work using cloudCode. Will post how i did it asap

Comment: can you post a sample for this if it is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Cloudcode function and upload it to Parse

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createNewUser", function(request, response) {

    // extract passed in details 
    var username = request.params.username
    var pw = request.params.password
    var email = request.params.email

    // cloud local calls
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("password", pw);
    user.set("email", email);

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {       
        //response.error("working");
        // do other stuff here 
        // like set ACL
        // create relationships
        // and then save again!! using user.save
        // you will need to use Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 

    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        //response.error("Sorry! " + error.message);
    } });

});
```

Call the cloud code function from within your app via. Pass in details to the clod function using a Dictionary, ["username":"", "password":""] etc

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground
```